# Dashboard Widget for Outlook:Mac2011 tasks

Tags: macos, ms-office, dashboard-widget

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.1 and Outlook for Mac 2011 (14.1.0); I am looking for a dashboard widget which could list all the tasks I have added in Outlook.

Is there one such dashboard widget available? From where can I download it?

Comment: Are you looking for a Dashboard Widget?

Comment: @jmlumpkin: yes, that should do!!

Comment: @jmlumpkin: updated the title as well!!

Answer (score 1):

I have not found one.  While I might prefer a widget, there is the "My Day" feature of Office 2011 for Mac, whose hide/show hotkey is Ctrl-M by default.  This will open an Agenda-like window for the day, with a snapshot of your calendar events for the day, as well as a short list of Outlook tasks.  What is shown is, of course, mildly configurable for both Outlook and local content.